# Pay out your salary from employer to employee in ADA (crypto)

Tags: wallet, ada, payment

How can I arrange for my company that I can pay my employee's in crypto ADA coins or crypto on the Cardano network?

I would like to facilitate my employee's that they have the option to pay a part of there salary in cryptocurrencies.

What are the possibility's within this matter, what is necessary for me to do or what is still being developed to get to this point?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your country. You should be well-acquainted with your responsibilities in terms of payroll withholding for taxes.

However, with respect to automating a system to pay your employees, I would recommend that when they would usually provide their banking details for direct-deposit, offer the alternative of instead providing a payment address to a Cardano wallet. At the end of every pay period, you can simply have Ada transferred to the wallet address on file instead of drafting a wire transfer.

If there is some concern that employees might lose access to their wallets, you could also offer to generate wallets with seed phrases for your employees so that both you and the employee knows that employee's seed phrase. Employees can then transfer their funds from their wallets immediately upon receipt; however, if an employee loses access to his or her wallet, you will be able to recover it for him or her.

I would also provide a receipt with the value of Ada upon sending it so that the employee will be able to calculate capital gains and losses to report to your country's version of the IRS. This will also provide you with a copy so that you can do the same.